# Advanced menu in Java with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu

I designed a menu using Java language and now I want each menu item to go to the desired page when clicked.
And one more thing is that I want to have a light and dark mode in my menu, how do I do it?
But I don't know, can you please introduce me the pages that have this training[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4oKB.jpg)

I have made the menu but I don't know how to add day and night mode
and opening each menu item in a separate page

Answer (score 0):

It is called Navigation Drawer, you can follow tutorial in this link to learn how to create it:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer